# Using python to run command line actions

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I am writing a program to constantly change my IP address. I have learned that methods from the subprocess module can be useful to write in the command line (such as `subclass.Popen`). In OS X, how can I put a function into python code to execute into the command line? In my case, I need (sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP && sudo ipconfig set en1 DHCP) executed in my python code.

Comment: As you write, you can use `subprocess.Popen()`. What have you tried?

Comment: @JohanL I tried subprocess.Popen(sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP && sudo ipconfig set en1 DHCP) and there was a format error. What is the correct way to use .Popen?

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.Popen("sudo command", shell=True)`

Should work for your case